# this.$emit vs. this.$root.$emit, best practice in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, event-handling

I have vue2 components that are added and removed with `v-if`.  In some cases I communicate between them with `$emit` from the sender, and `$on` in the receiver.

I've been using `this.$root.$emit` to broadcast custom events and `this.$root.$on` to handle the events.  I've discovered using `this.$root.$on` requires `this.$root.$off` (from `beforeDestroy`), otherwise the removed component may attempt to handle it, and bad things happen.

I have two questions:

1. What's the difference between `this.$root.$emit` and `this.$emit`?
2. If I use `this.$on`, do I also have to pair it with `this.$off`?  Or will the handler automatically go "off" when the component is removed?

Comment: Just as a heads up, usually root emits are never a good idea, unless some particular case. To back this up in fact vue3 removed its support. I'm not even sure why you would need $on, as even those are pretty much edge cases.

Comment: @CristianoSoleti Really? How is the use of $on edge case? I use them a lot to react on changes in other vue components. Did I miss something? How else can you communicate between components?

Comment: Using the listeners as vue suggests. 
  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events

Answer (score 8):

> 1. What's the difference between `this.$root.$emit` and `this.$emit`?

[`this.$root`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-root) gets the root component instance (usually `App.vue`), so `this.$root.emit` emits an event from the root component.

`this.$emit` simply emits an event from the current component.

> 2. If I use `this.$on`, do I also have to pair it with `this.$off`? Or will the handler automatically go "off" when the component is removed?

`this.$off` is not needed. Yes, the handler will automatically be removed when the component is destroyed.