# Vue 2 emit not running method, even though setup correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to emit an event from a child Vue component to it's parent, I'm trying to do this with `this.$emit('collapsemenu')`.

When I'm trying to get this event from the parent with `v-on:collapsemenu="collapseMenuf($event)"` nothing happens at all. The method does not run, but I'm sure the child event emits the event.

Am I missing something important here? I've tried to look for similar problems online, but nothing has worked so far.

**Navbar (Child)**

```
<template>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-left">
      <svg
        @click="collapse_menu"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        class="hamburger"
        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
        fill="currentColor"
      >
        <path
          fill-rule="evenodd"
          d="M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 15a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1z"
          clip-rule="evenodd"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-right"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Navbars",
  components: {},
  methods: {
    collapse_menu() {
      console.log("clicked");
      this.$emit("collapsemenu", "TRUE");
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;

  &-left {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

.hamburger {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
}
</style>
```

**Main**

```
<template>
  <div class="dashboard h-screen bg-red-200">
    <Menu class="menu"></Menu>

    <div class="content">
      <Navbar v-on:collapsemenu="collapseMenuf($event)"></Navbar>
    </div>
    <!-- <Content></Content> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from "../../components/dashboard/navbar.vue";
import Menu from "../../components/dashboard/menu.vue";
export default {
  name: "Dash-main",
  components: { Navbar, Menu },
  data() {
    return {
      collapse: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    collapseMenuf(value) {
      console.log("fsd");
      this.collapse = value;
      console.log(value);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.dashboard {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting just the function name into the `v-on` directive?
`v-on:collapsemenu="collapseMenuf"`

Comment: @akopyl Thank you for your reply. Yes I have, this also does not seem to do anything at all. No console log is shown and there are no erros.

Comment: I just copied your code into a fresh vue project and it seems to work for me as is.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible stackblitz example?

Comment: Ah, you're right, this wasn't a Vue problem, but a webpack one. Webpack did not load correctly, it didn't apply all the changes, and needed to be restarted. Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

From the parent component you should do it as this:

```
  <Navbar v-on:collapsemenu="collapseMenuf"></Navbar>
```

Child component:

```
<svg
    @click="collapse_menu($event)"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    class="hamburger"
    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
    fill="currentColor"
  >
```

Access this `$event` inside a function like this:

```
const collapse_menu = (e) => {
  console.log(e);
  emit('click', e.target);
};
```

You can find more about vue emits [here](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/emits-option.html#migration-strategy)

Answer (score 0):

this is little bit confusing. I had face the same problem.
Though documentation of vue.js-v2 said that these

```
// on child component
this.$emit('event-name')
// on parent template
<child-component-name v-on:event-name="parent-method"></child-component-name>
```

should work. But unfortunately it didn't.

I had solved my problem by this:

```
// on child component
this.$root.$emit('saveSettings', this.apiRequestSetupObj);
// in parent component add this on mount
const thisInstance = this
this.$on('saveSettings', function (data) {
         thisInstance.saveSettings(data);
});
```

So you can try this out.

note: If you want to know the difference between this.$emit vs this.$root.$emit, then check this question: [this.$emit vs. this.$root.$emit, best practice in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68147098/this-emit-vs-this-root-emit-best-practice-in-vuejs)