# difference between using this.$emit and this.$root.$emit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

is there a difference between using **$emit** directly and **$root.$emit** ?
=> **this.$emit('default-choice', this.choice);** & **this.$root.$emit('default-choice', this.choice);**

`` `this.$emit('default-choice', this.choice);` ``

`` `this.$root.$emit('default-choice', this.choice); ``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [this.$emit vs. this.$root.$emit, best practice in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68147098/this-emit-vs-this-root-emit-best-practice-in-vuejs)

Comment: @yoduh well that answer gives an idea, but when should I **emit an event from the root component** and when I just need to emit it from the **current componenet** ?

Comment: it's not really recommended but `this.$root.$emit` combined with `this.$root.$on` can act as a sort of global event bus.  The vue 2 [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced) recommend using a separate vue instance instead.  a state management library can also serve the same purpose

Comment: Event bus was always some kind of weird middle ground tho and could also be ignored in favor of more official approaches: props/emit + store.

Comment: @yoduh so if I use **this.$emit** I don't need to set the listener **this.$root.$on** ? then which is the form to listen to that event ?

Comment: Listen with [v-on](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) directive in your parent component

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to use root emit for any case. It's really good to have emit we can emit to the parent component but when it comes to root emit if you ever think "I need to use root emit" then think again and try to use something else (ex: vuex).

and also in Vue.js 3 they removed $on, $once and $off instance methods

https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0020-events-api-change.md

> Vue 1.x implemented the component event system similar to that of AngularJS, with $dispatch and $broadcast where components in a tree can communicate by sending events up and down the tree. In Vue 2, we removed $dispatch and $broadcast in favor of a more state-driven data flow (props down, events up). With Vue 2's API, $emit can be used to trigger event handlers declaratively attached by a parent component (in templates or render functions), but can also be used to trigger handlers attached imperatively via the event emitter API ($on, $off and $once). This is in fact an overload: the full event emitter API isn't a part of the typical inter-component data-flow. They are rarely used, and there are really no strong reason for them to be exposed via component instances. This RFC therefore proposes to remove the $on, $off and $once instance methods

Comment: Vue3 is also the default as of right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something global, you'll use a store.

An `$emit` is meant to be used from parent to child and is the probably the one you'll be using 99% of your time.

On top of that, the documentation doesn't really approach the `$root.$emit` last time I checked. Hence that one could be ignored.

Keep things simple, it will be easier to debug thanks to Vue devtools.